# Looping over all members of a class

Tags: salesforce, apex

In apex, if I want to loop over all members of a "inner" class & create a map from it (member name to its value).
How do I do that?

Thanks in advance.

```
public class fromJSON{
```

public boolean success;
public Integer timestamp;  //1646140623
public String base;    //EUR
public String dateJ;   //2022-03-01
public Map<String, Decimal> rates;
public cls_rates rates;

```
 class cls_rates {
     public Double AED; 
     public Double AFN; 
     public Double ALL; 
     public Double AMD; 
     public Double ANG; 
     public Double AOA; 
     public Double ARS; 
     public Double AUD; 
     public Double AWG; 
     public Double AZN; 
     public Double BAM; 
     public Double BBD; 
     public Double BDT; 
     public Double BGN; 
     public Double BHD; 
     public Double BIF; 
     public Double BMD; 
     public Double BND; 
     public Double BOB; 
     public Double BRL; 
     public Double BSD; 
     public Double BTC; 
     public Double BTN; 
     public Double BWP; 
     public Double BYN; 
     public Double BYR; 
     public Double BZD; 
     public Double CAD; 
     public Double CDF; 
     public Double CHF; 
     public Double CLF; 
}
```

}

Comment: add the code sample as actual code, not a screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may need to **serialize** the inner class object and we would need to **deserialize** it using  **deserializeUntyped**  method for holding the inner class members variables into a map.

```
//Create a instance of the inner class
fromJSON.cls_rates rates=new fromJSON.cls_rates();

//Setting some variable for demo purpose
rates.AED = 10.0;

//Serializing the inner class instance to json string 
String jsonStr = JSON.serialize(rates);


//Deserializing the json string to a map with key and values from the inner class
Map<String, Object> jsonMap = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonStr);

System.debug('jsonMap : '+jsonMap);
```